# Function call spanning multiple lines in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a C# function call which looks something like this:

```
var res = function ("arg1",   // argument# 1
                    "arg2",   // argument# 2
                    "arg3"    // argument# 3
                   );
```

the list of arguments is around 25 or so. It's a Web Services function, which I have no control over.

I'm trying to port it to VB.NET for another application and was wondering if VB.NET will let me call a function in this manner (with comments, if possible)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Dim res = function("arg1", _
                  "arg2", _
                  "arg3" _
                    )
```

Will work, however you can't add comments to each line, as the `_` character has to be the last character on the line.

Answer (score 7):

FYI, the next version of VB will let you write the call like this:

```
Dim res = function("arg1",
                   "arg2",
                   "arg3"
                  )
```

I.e. without underscores to continue the lines.

Comment: Yes! This answer is more than seven years old. The version in question was VB10, which has been out for almost as long.

Answer (score 0):

It will not.  You can use the built-in XML comments to add comments to the function declaration.  In VS simply type "'''" above the function and it will automatically generate a comment body for you to fill out.

If you want to list your parameters on a function call in that way, you can use the line continuation character "_" following each parameter to list the function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you desire the `_` line continuation character.

Comment: Continued lines cannot contain comments, unfortunately, despite developers continuously requesting this feature since .NET 2003 beta 1.

Comment: Not really, VB is the reason there is a C# :-D

Comment: @Achilles Please elaborate, as I know no such reason.